# Cisco Nexus 5000 VTP trunk status in vPC consistency-parameter

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus-5k, vpc, cisco-nx-os

In a pair of Nexus 5000, the show vpc consistency-parameters command
displays VTP trunk status on only one Nexus Enabled. The config is
identical, what is the reason for the discrepancy?

```
# sh vpc consistency-parameters vpc 10

    Legend:
        Type 1 : vPC will be suspended in case of mismatch

Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
-------------               ----  ---------------------- -----------------------
Shut Lan                    1     No                     No
STP Port Type               1     Default                Default
STP Port Guard              1     None                   None
STP MST Simulate PVST       1     Default                Default
lag-id                      1     [(7f9b,                [(7f9b,
                                  0-23-4-ee-be-a, 8081,  0-23-4-ee-be-a, 8081,
                                  0, 0), (8000,          0, 0), (8000,
                                  e4-1f-13-d8-44-ea,     e4-1f-13-d8-44-ea,
                                  beef, 0, 0)]           beef, 0, 0)]
mode                        1     active                 active
Speed                       1     10 Gb/s                10 Gb/s
Duplex                      1     full                   full
Port Mode                   1     trunk                  trunk
Native Vlan                 1     1                      1
MTU                         1     1500                   1500
Admin port mode             1
VTP trunk status            2     -                      Enabled
Allowed VLANs               -     100,201                100,201
Local suspended VLANs       -     -                      -
```

Comment: What is the VTP mode on both devices?

Comment: VTP Mode on both N3K is set to Server, running version: 1

Comment: Just for information, I'm having this issue on N7K too

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `-` character indicates VTP is disabled.

As Fizzle says, `show vtp status` should reveal the discrepancy.

There is a [bug on the N3K](https://tools.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCuj31678) that causes this behavior even if they're currently set the same if you have ever enabled VTP the box still thinks its on.   Perhaps that bug also exists on N5K if show vpc status shows the same state.

In any case since its a type 2 inconsistency it doesn't affect traffic flow.

Comment: VTP is enabled and running on both N3K. Guess it's the same bug you mentioned, which causes the incorrect output of `sh vpc consistency-parameters`.